# Correlation using workflows

Tags: workflow, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4, workflowservice

I have 3 receive send activities. I have configured first send and second receive activities as per the documents.

Refer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg535671.aspx

My first 2 operation contracts are working good. But when i call my final receive activity I get the following error message

> The execution of an InstancePersistenceCommand was interrupted because
>   the instance key '761c9e4a-2835-d6ec-6017-581a5fbfb741' was not
>   associated to an instance. This can occur because the instance or key
>   has been cleaned up, or because the key is invalid. The key may be
>   invalid if the message it was generated from was sent at the wrong
>   time or contained incorrect correlation data.

I am sure this happens when my 3rd receive activity is not able to correlate to 2 send activity. But I am not sure how do configure the 2nd send activity among these correlations Initializers.

I am using workflowservice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should configure the third Receive activity exactly the same way as the second and use the same correlation value when doing the 3rd operation.

Comment: Should we do something with second send activity correlation initializer. If not I did exactly same as the second receive activity.

Comment: No, the initializer is only used with the initial request with a specific correlation value. Its job is to do the correlation setup for that value.

Comment: So there should not be any Correlation Initializer for the Second Send activity (no handle). Is that right? But I get the same error?